# comparing array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a following json(sample data) which i get from the another URL

```
var data = [
{ id: 1, name: 'ravi', parentid: 0 },
{ id: 2, name: 'raj', parentid: 1 },
{ id: 3, name: 'ram', parentid: 1 },
{ id: 4, name: 'raja', parentid: 0 },
{ id: 5, name: 'raju', parentid: 4 },       
{ id: 6, name: 'dinesh', parentid: 4 }  
];
```

When i get success message in angular, i want to compare data which has id 
of `parentid` zero with `parentid` of remaining data.I tried following code but i am not able to proceed more than this

```
$http.get('URL')
    .success(function(data) {
        var categories = data;
        for(var i =0;i<=categories.length;i++)
        {
            if(typeof categories[i] != "undefined" && categories[i].parentId == 0)
            {
                $scope.cat.push(categories[i]);
            }   
            if($scope.cat[i].parentid == categories[i].id)
            {
                $scope.content.push(categories[i]);
            }           
        }

    });
```

here i want to compare `categories[i].parentId` with `$scope.cat.id` and inserted into array but while comparing this i am getting an error like `$scope.cat[i]` is `undefined`
finally my output look like below

```
Ravi
  raj
  ram
raja
  raju
  dinesh
```

Comment: `i<=categories.length` should be `i<categories.length` in your for loop

Comment: still  i am getting Error: $scope.cat[i] is undefined

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where `$scope.cat` is defined. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: even i declared $scope.cat = [] at starting of code i am getting same error

Comment: i pushed data into $scope.cat but when i compared parentid and id i am getting this error

Comment: are you sure that you push data into `$scope.cat`. because, what if, the control is not going to your 1st `if` loop ?

Comment: Can't tell what your `$scope.cat` is but it's length is obviously not the same length as `categories` so you're getting this error. Can't tell why with what you've provided

Comment: yes you are right length of categories and $scope.cat will not be same.is there any way to compare those id and parent id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face 3 problems listed below:

1. In `if(typeof categories[i] != "undefined" && categories[i].parentId == 0)` you are comparing `parentId` and it never is as your property name is `parentid` (check casing). And hence, your 1st `if` loop is never executed and that is why your `$scope.cat` remains undefined.

Solution: correct the typo for `parentId`

2. In, `if($scope.cat[i].parentid == categories[i].id)` you are comparing the parent id of parent elements with id's of child element.

Solution: `if($scope.cat[i].id == categories[i].parentid)`

3. You are using same iterator for two list items with different lenghts.

Solution:

```
 var categories = data;

 // fill $scope.cat with elements having parent id = 0, so this list will contain all the parent elements
 $scope.cat = categories.filter(function(category) {
     return category && category.parentid === 0
 });
 $scope.content = [];
 // fill $scope.content with elements whose parent exist in $scope.cat (the parent list craeted above)
 categories.forEach(function(category) {
     if ($scope.cat.filter(function(cat) {
             return category.parentid === cat.id
         }).length > 0)
         $scope.content.push(category);
 });
```

sample [plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dwECDDNgdwW8ijf5TfoJ?p=preview)

Comment: even i change categories[i].parentid i am getting same error

Comment: @user7098427: I have updated my answer with the optimized code, have a look

Comment: i am getting undefined in my console if i use your code.could you please show me in plnkr

Comment: i have updated my answer with sample plunk, have a look. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

replace

```
if($scope.cat[i].parentid == categories[i].id)
            {
                $scope.content.push(categories[i]);
            }
```

with

```
var res = $scope.cat.filter(function(item){
  return item.parentid === categories[i].id;
});

if(res.length)
{
    $scope.content.push(categories[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try what I suggested added what u should replace, my only concern is you may need to use the filter to match up the content and cat arrrays with ids.

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` for `$scope.cat[i]` because the code that pushes to `$scope.cat` is not always executed even after correcting `parentId` to `parentid`

```
if(typeof categories[i] != "undefined" && categories[i].parentid == 0)
{
                $scope.cat.push(categories[i]);
}
```

for some values of the data array this condition will not be true. So nothing will be pushed to `$scope.cat`.

and remember your second `if` statement comes just after your first `if` statement. So sometimes you will not have `$scope.cat[i]`

for all these values the code will not be executed beacuse they dont pass the condition

```
{ id: 2, name: 'raj', parentid: 1 },
{ id: 3, name: 'ram', parentid: 1 },
{ id: 5, name: 'raju', parentid: 4 },       
{ id: 6, name: 'dinesh', parentid: 4 }
```

since `parent id` is not `0`

So these are the values causing `undefined`

**you can change to :**

```
var categories = data;
    for(var i =0;i<=categories.length;i++)
    {
        if(typeof categories[i] != "undefined" && categories[i].parentid ==0)
        {
            $scope.cat.push(categories[i]);
        }

    }
    //you will already have you $scope.cat filled then loop through it 
    //checking with the categories array too.

    for(var j=0;j<$scope.cat.length;j++)
    {
       for(var k=0; k<categories.length; k++){
         if($scope.cat[j].parentid==categories[k].id)
         {
           $scope.content.push(categories[k]);
         }
       }
    }
```

**or something like :**

```
var categories = data;

categories = categories
.filter( (category)=>{
   return (category !== []._);  //removes all undefineds in the array
})
.map((category)=>{
  //checks each category from data if is parent_Id is 0 and pushes it to cats array
  //by the end of the operation. the cats array will have some data
  (category.parentId == 0)? ($scope.cats.push(category) , return ) : return;
})
var getContent =(cats,categories)=>{
  var content=[];
  for(var j=0;j<cats.length;j++)
  {
     for(var k=0; k<categories.length; k++){
       if(cats[j].parentid==categories[k].id)
       {
         content.push(categories[k]);
       }
     }
  }
  return content;
}
$scope.content = getContent($scope.cats,categories);
```

Comment: in this case i have two data in $scope.cat.so i want to compare only id of these two datas with parentid of remaining data

Comment: remember your second if statement comes just after your first if stattement. So sometimes you will not have Scope.cat[i]